# Recursive bash directory

Tags: bash, recursion

I am using the recursive bash for lopping through each directory. In each directory the files are present in the form of the `New_File_Naming.Y1.txt` and `New_File_Naming.Y2.txt` and I am trying to ran a command recursively in each directory like :

`find . -type -d -exec sh -c '(cd {} && cat {}.Y1.txt {}.Y2.txt)' ';'`

However i am getting an error that the file names are the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please include the verbatim error message.

Comment: If you're putting together a name of a directory and a filename, you should use `/`, not `.`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c '(cat {}/New_File_Naming.Y1.txt {}/New_File_Naming.Y2.txt)' ';'
```

should work.

Comment: Hi sami thanks for this but I think this will go for only one directory and not recursively. In each directory we have files with the Y1 and Y2.

Comment: I think that you should actually do `find . -name "New_File_Naming*" -exec ...` instead, if all you want is to find all files named "New_File_Naming.*.txt".

Comment: Hi Sami, I am not using the find . -name as the New_File_naming is different in each folder. so for example one folder as New_File_naming_Y1.txt and New_file_naming_y2.txt and another folder has New_File_naming_something_Y1.txt and New_File_naming_something_Y2.txt. the thing is that Y1 and Y2 is constant for each file in filename.

Comment: The answer is still obvious: instead of doing something overly complex, try concoct a pattern that matches only the files you want to find, then feed that to `find -name "<pattern here>"`. For example, if you know files you want to find have "Y1" and "Y2" in their names, simply use `find -name "*Y1*" -name "*Y2*" -exec cat {} \;`.